# How type checking in Typescript works with passing argument?

Tags: object, typescript, types, literals

With TypeScript, could anyone explain for me why the two function calls below give different type checking result?

```
interface LabelledValue {
    label: string;
}

function printLabel(labelledObj: LabelledValue) {
    console.log(labelledObj.label);
}

var myObj = {size: 10, label: "Size 10 Object"};

//This calls is OK

**printLabel(myObj);**

//But this call is warned with error "size doe snot exist in LabelledValue

**printLabel({ size: 10, label: "Size 10 Object" });**
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a deliberate decision by authors of TypeScript. Having excess properties in object literal is likely a result of a typo, so it's diagnosed as error. Also, with code like the second call of `printLabel` in your question, `size` property is not going to be used anywhere, so there is no point in having it in object literal there.

[Quote from the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks):

> However, TypeScript takes the stance that there’s probably a bug in
>   this code. Object literals get special treatment and undergo excess
>   property checking when assigning them to other variables, or passing
>   them as arguments. If an object literal has any properties that the
>   “target type” doesn’t have, you’ll get an error.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, typescript implicitly casts an object of type `{ size: number, label: string }` to `LabelledValue`, which works fine.

In the second case, typescript thinks you are trying to create an object of type `LabelledValue`, so it gets mad because `size` is not a valid property.

You would get the same error in the first case if you assigned a type to `myObj`, e.g.

```
var myObj: LabelledValue = {size: 10, label: "Size 10 Object"}; // causes compiler error
```

I don't know what you are trying to do with this, but one possible workaround would be to add `size` as an optional property of your interface, like this:

```
interface LabelledValue {
    label: string;
    size?: number;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain why in the first case, the cast from an object of type `{size: number, label: string}` to `LabelledValue` works fine? I am confused because `LabelledValue` only defines property `label` and does not define property `size`. Thanks.

Comment: The main purpose of the `LabelledValue` interface is to ensure that the `label` property exists. Since the type of `myObj` (`{ label: string, size: number }`) contains the label property, it is assignable to type `LabelledValue`.

Comment: It only doesn't work when passing an object literal as a parameter to the function (e.g. `printLabel({ size: 10, label: "Size 10 Object" })`), because there is no point in passing a `size` property in that case, because the `printLabel` function can't use it.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript allows certain un-sound operations that can’t be known at compile-time to be safe.

```
printLabel(myObj);  // un-sound operation
```

[Quote from Typescript handbook:](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html)

> The basic rule for TypeScript’s structural type system is that x is
>   compatible with y if y has at least the same members as x

Here ***obj*** is type compatible with ***LabelledValue*** since ***obj*** has all the members ***LabelledValue*** require (i.e. `label: string`)

However the following gives a compile error since object literal can only specify known properties:

```
printLabel({ size: 10, label: "Size 10 Object" });  // ERROR
```

To correct this error, simply explicitly cast the object literal as `<LabelledValue>`:

```
printLabel(<LabeledValue>{ size: 10, label: "Size 10 Obect" });  // OK
```